# Linear Algebra - linear transformation- range of T

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\ T:\Bbb R^3\rightarrow \Bbb R^3$ be the linear tranformation defined by
$\ T(a,b,c)=(2a-b,a+b+c,-a+c)$,

Find a basis for the Range (T).

I already solved the standard matrix $\ A=
$$ \left[    
  \begin{matrix}
    2 & -1 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 1 \\
    -1 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{matrix}
\right] $$
$ and $ R_A=
$$ \left[    
  \begin{matrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{matrix}
\right] $$
$ (if I was solving correctly). can $\ Range(T)=Col(A)=Col (R_A)$ in this case?

Comment: What is $\mathbb R_A$? A row-reduced version of $A$? If so, why didn’t you reduce it all the way to the identity matrix?

Comment: @amd you were right, I fixed the R_A now.

Comment: OK. It should now be pretty obvious what the range of $T$ is. Note, though, that in general $Col(A)\ne Col(R_A)$. Compare the column spaces of, say, $\tiny{\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}}$ and its RREF $\tiny{\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}}$.

Comment: @amd in this case,col (A)=col (R_A), then what is the span? is it span={[2,1,-1], [-1,1,0], [0,1,1]} or span{[1,0,1], [0,1,0], [0,0,1]}. Becasue I remember what I learned that if col (A)=col (R_A), the span of the columns of A should be the latter one, otherwise, if col (A) is not equal to col (R_A), then we use the former one.

Comment: The range is **all** of $\mathbb R^3$. Pick any basis of it that you like.

Comment: @amd I do not understand

Comment: Normally, you’d take the columns of $A$ that correspond to pivots in the RREF. In this case, though, since the range consists of the entire codomain, then _any_ linearly-independent set of 3 vectors will do, including the columns of the RREF.

Comment: @amd I know in general Col(A)≠Col(RA), but in this case, they are equal, right??

Comment: @amd so are you saying both span={[2,1,-1], [-1,1,0], [0,1,1]} and span{[1,0,1], [0,1,0], [0,0,1]} are correct?

Answer (score 1):

You have a small typo in the first column of your $A$ matrix.

The range of $T$ is the span of the columns of $A$. If the columns are linearly independent, then you automatically have a basis for the range.

Comment: so I guess the basis for the range is exactly the same as matrix A.

Comment: by the way, I already fixed my typo, thanks.

Comment: @angryvarian in this case,col (A)=col (R_A), then what is the span? is it span={[2,1,-1], [-1,1,0], [0,1,1]} or span{[1,0,1], [0,1,0], [0,0,1]}. Becasue I remember what I learned that if col (A)=col (R_A), the span of the columns of A should be the latter one, otherwise, if col (A) is not equal to col (R_A), then we use the former one.

Comment: @A.H In this case the column space is $\mathbb{R}^3$, which can be written as the span of any three linearly independent vectors. Both of the ones you suggested will work.

Answer (score 1):

The basis for a set of vectors must be linearly independent. As you've stated we are searching for the basis of $Range(T)$. As you've noted $T$ can be given by $A$, that is to say $T:\overrightarrow{x} \mapsto A\overrightarrow{x}$. Using this notation, it is a bit clearer to see that $Range(T)=A\overrightarrow{x}$. Notice $A\overrightarrow{x} = x_1 \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\
1 \\
-1 \\\end {bmatrix}+x_2\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\
1 \\
0 \\\end {bmatrix}+x_3\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\
1 \\
1 \\\end {bmatrix}$. Setting this vector equation equal to $0$ will allow one to solve for linear independence. Since a set of vectors $\{v_0,v_1, \dots ,v_n \}$ is defined to be linearly independent if and only if the only solution to $c_0v_0+c_1v_1+\dots+c_nv_n=0$ is for all $c_i=0$. So, using an augmented matrix $B,$  $B=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 &0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
-1 & 0 & 1& 0\end{bmatrix}$. Using Gauss-Jordan reduction gives $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
0&1&0&0 \\ 
0&0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$. Since these solutions are unique, the previously mentioned vector equation is in fact linearly independent. As a result it is a suitable basis for $Range(T)$.

Comment: sorry, there was a typo in the first column of my A matrix, I already fixed it.

Comment: in this case,col (A)=col (R_A), then what is the span? is it span={[2,1,-1], [-1,1,0], [0,1,1]} or span{[1,0,1], [0,1,0], [0,0,1]}. Becasue I remember what I learned that if col (A)=col (R_A), the span of the columns of A should be the latter one, otherwise, if col (A) is not equal to col (R_A), then we use the former one. @Luke Paluso

Comment: You have a few choices, I would suggest fully reducing $A$ down to the identity matrix, and then considering the three standard basis vectors as the span. It is also true in this case however, that both spans that you mentioned  would be suitable picks. Since the matrix can be reduced to the Identity matrix, it represents a transformation that spans $\mathbb{R^{3}}$. Technically, any linearly independent set of vectors that spans $\mathbb{R^{3}}$ is a suitable span. 

But if your professor suggests using a specific standard, I would advise following their suggestion :)